# ShareIntent for Text Form TextView

Tags: android, eclipse, textview, gettext

Does anyone of you have a solution for getting a share button to share a text settled to a TextView by another button?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextView.getText()` to get the text on a specific `TextView` object.

Note that `getText()` returns a `CharSequence` but you can obtain the `String` using `toString()` method.

And you can check [here](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html) for the appropriate share intent.

Comment: With the getText().toString method I always get the default text from the XML file. Not the one that was set by TextView.setText(String)...